# chrome opacity overlay overflow issue affect to border radius

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, opacity, css

```
$("#page-circle").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('span').animate({"opacity":0.4},{queue:false});
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('span').animate({"opacity":0},{queue:false});
});
```

this problem is only in chrome browser;
the span parent overflow is set to hidden;

here is span css:

```
#page-circle span{  
    position:absolute;  
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    bottom:0px;
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:right;
    padding:8px 10px;
    background-image:url(../images/bg-overlay.png);
    background-color:#000;
}
```

link to jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/T4mer/zjr9Y/

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to this running or on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T4mer/zjr9Y/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting a `border-radius`on your span like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zjr9Y/3/

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: latest one Version 25.0.1364.172 m